# What Landmark am I missing in the Emerald Graves?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

[image: Map]

I have run up and down the map a dozen times now, I've been pretty much everywhere but I simply can't find the last landmark that I am missing. I've included a screenshot of my map, so if somebody has completed the entire map, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could point out where the landmark I'm missing is located at.

Sadly enough, it doesn't seem like anybody has made a landmark guide yet, hence me having to ask the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last one is at the top of the map behind the Dragon

Comment: I've actually been there and killed the dragon, but I must have missed the landmark somewhow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Top right of the map in the area with the dragon.  It doesn't look like you've even been up there.

Answer (score 0):

It's back behind where the dragon is located,  it's to the right of the wolf statue.